# HttpClient.SendAsync unsupported media type

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

As usual, in .NET 4.5, I used a HttpClient to send a get request to restful service (a remote server)

However, this time, it returned error `415 - Unsupported Media Type`.

I'm expecting the request header including `Content-Type = application/json`.
And I cannot find a way to set Content-Type correctly.

Anybody has experience for this case or any suggestion will be appreciated!

The code is as below and the httpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.Headers
[image]

---

**Updated 1**

### As I researched, I cannot add a retricted header for Content-Type. Since this is 4.5 implementation. Is this correct?

**Updated 2**

I tried to add

```
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

However it returned `Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type`

Comment: any reason why you are using SendAsync and then doing a Result, which blocks the call and defeats the purpose of async?

Comment: I just want a synchronous call. Is there a better way?

Comment: yes, don't use the Async version.

Comment: I dont see any Send without Async for httpclient. .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that your server is not complaining about the invalid content type you *requested* but about the content type you *sent* with that request.

That you get

> Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

seems to hint that your tried to send a **GET** request. It is rather unusual (allthough technically the HTTP protocol allows this) that servers require a **GET** request with a body. So my best guess is that there is something wrong with the server.

Comment: It did not work, since the get request has no content (request.Content = null). And even when I can, it will returned "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.". verb-type = Get